# Power Dissipated by Resistor in AC Circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, power

I'm having a problem with the following review question:

Given the circuit:

[image]

I am asked to find the power dissipated by R1 and C. I know that for C it is 0. For R1, I know I need to use Vrms (120*rt2 V/rt2) = 120 V. I'm stuck as to where to go from here. I thought about using a voltage divider to find the voltage on R1, then using V^2/R to get the power, but I don't know how to do this with three resistors.

Comment: Please read [this meta post on homework-style questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: Hi Liam and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it into two problems. First, consider the three resistors in series, and replace them with a single equivalent resistor. Now you can figure out how much current flows through the capacitor, and how much through the resistor. You correctly figured out there is no power dissipation through the capacitor, since current and voltage will be in quadrature; and since there is no internal impedance on the voltage source, the current through the resistor doesn't depend on the presence of the capacitor.

Once you know how much current is flowing, you can remove the capacitor and figure out what fraction of the current flows through the resistor you are asked about. And use $\frac12 I^2 R$ to obtain the power.